# How to customize d3plus large tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3plus

I am making a visualisation with d3plus.here is my fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/kasimsert/wLvpph35/11/
I want to make some basic custom processing over elements like tooltips, rectangles etc.However I could not find a way to do it with d3 selectors.As far as I see problem is when selector function works this elements are not there. For this I have added onLoad function to html body but no change. My question is when in the code flow I should call such code blocks in order to take effect?

```
d3.select(".d3plus_tooltip_container")
    .style("background-color", 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
.tooltip({
    "share":false,
    "html" : "Summary information about the Service, and may be some links to the external applications",
    "font": {size:"auto"},
    "background": "red" // add this
})
```

Check documentation [here](https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/wiki/Visualizations#tooltip).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I also need to draw a line plot on the large tooltip, and as far as I see I can do such things only with accessing these elements via d3. Do you have any idea how to do this ?

Comment: That's a considerable jump from your original "basic custom processing". But this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291723/how-to-add-a-tooltip-that-shows-a-bar-chart-onto-a-d3-js-map#29294371) should get you going.

Comment: The difference between my problem and the linked one is I am using d3plus for drawing.And after drawing and then using d3 selectors, nothing returns.